BigCommerce - Disable Add To Cart unless Quantity Matches set Value of Pick List?
I am trying to create the option for the customer to Build Their Own Bundle. I have used Papa Themes multiple quantity product options app, so that the customer can set a Quantity above one, but what I would like to achieve, is to disable the 'Add To Cart' button for a particular product until the customer picks a total of 8 products in the pick list - no more, or no less.
For instance, I have a test product here: https://wolftucker.co.uk/byo-food-bundle-test
I want to restrict the customer to only purchase a total of 8 meals (no more, or less) and the add to cart button ideally would be disabled until they have selected 8 and then it is available for them to add to cart.
Once added to cart, as they will be added as a 'product option' under the main product being 'BYO Food Bundle' - I would like to grey out the quantity options in the cart so they can't modify the numbers once in the cart... is this all possible? and how might I go about implementing this?
Thank you so much for any advice you can offer :)
Kindest regards
I tried to restrict the quantity options to a set value, which I was able to do on each option but I do not understand how to apply this to an overall value for all product options and how to disable and then enable the add to cart button for said product
